# tengo este problema con el conect de qt

Tags: qt

Me salta error en la siguietne línea de códigio:

```
 connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this,x,y]() { lab.eliminarArtefactoPosible(x,y); });
```

El error que me informa es:

> no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(QTimer*&, void (QTimer::*)(QTimer::QPrivateSignal), MainWindow*, MainWindow::dibujarArtefacto()::)'
>
> connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, this,x,y { lab.eliminarArtefactoPosible(x,y); });

Función entera del error:

```
 void MainWindow::dibujarArtefacto() {

    int x = rand() % configuracion.tamanio;
    int y = rand() % configuracion.tamanio;
    lab.generarArtefacto(x,y);
    redibujar();
    QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
    connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this,x,y]() { lab.eliminarArtefactoPosible(x,y); });
```

Clase que quiero conectar:

```
void Laberinto::eliminarArtefactoPosible(int x, int y) {

    if (!mapa[x][y]->es_solido()) {
        delete mapa[x][y];
        mapa[x][y] = new Piso();
    }
  }
```

Acá MainWindow.h:

```
namespace Ui {

    class MainWindow;
    }

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {

    Q_OBJECT
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    public:
      explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
      ~MainWindow();
      void redibujar();
    private:
      QLabel *** labels;
      QLabel *status;
      Laberinto lab;

      QAction *guardarAct;
      QAction *cargarAct;
      QMenu *archivoMenu;

    void crearMenus();

    private slots:
      void dibujarArtefacto();
      void cargarPartida();
      void guardarPartida();
```

Comment: creo que aqui `connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this,x,y]() { lab.eliminarArtefactoPosible(x,y); });` te sobra un `;` y queda asi `connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this,x,y]() { lab.eliminarArtefactoPosible(x,y) });`

Comment: @abrahamhs me sigue tirando el error

Comment: Por favor, no uses mayúsculas sin sentido. Es de mala educación y el texto se lee peor

Answer (score 0):

```
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this,x,y]() { lab.eliminarArtefactoPosible(x,y); });
```

La sintaxis de la sobrecarga de `connect` que estás usando es la siguiente:

```
connect(SENDER, SIGNAL, RECEIVER, SLOT)
```

En este caso, el problema se encuentra en que la lambda **no pertenece** a `this` (no es una función miembro).

Si quieres usar una lambda te sobra el tercer argumento:

```
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [this,x,y]() { lab.eliminarArtefactoPosible(x,y); });
```